# flutter listview bottom overflowed

Tags: listview, flutter, widget, height

I have two horizontal listview in my flutter applicatioin.I get an error when I put the second listview.
I used nestedscrollview to scroll page but this problem did not solve.How to manage the height of widgets so that this error does not occur?I tried to set height for second listview but it still made an error 
look at my codes:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
        theme: ThemeData(
          fontFamily: "Vazir",
          primaryColor: Colors.red,
          accentColor: Colors.green,
        ),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: Directionality(
          textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
          child: Scaffold(
              drawer: myDrawerLayout(context),
              body: NestedScrollView(
                headerSliverBuilder: (context, bool innerScroll) {
                  return <Widget>[
                    SliverAppBar(
                        title: Text(
                      "فروشگاه",
                      style: TextStyle(fontFamily: "Vazir"),
                    ))
                  ];
                },
                body: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    _imageSlider(),
                    _explanationTextForAmazingProduct(),//text for listview explanation
                    _SizedBox(
                      height: 190,
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: productList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return productList.isEmpty || productList == null
                                ? wiatingView()
                                : Card(
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 200,
                                      height: 70,
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Padding(
                                            padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: 80,
                                              height: 80,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                                          productList[index]
                                                              .getImage()))),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                right: 8, left: 8, top: 8),
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(productList[index]
                                                  .getTitle()),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              productList[index].getPrice(),
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.green),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                          }),
                    ),
                    explanationTextForMostSellProduct(),//text for second listview explanation
                    Expanded(
                      child: ListView.builder(
                          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          itemCount: productList.length,
                          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            return productList.isEmpty || productList == null
                                ? wiatingView()
                                : Card(
                                    child: Container(
                                      width: 200,
                                      height: 150,
                                      child: Column(
                                        children: <Widget>[
                                          Padding(
                                            padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8),
                                            child: Container(
                                              width: 80,
                                              height: 80,
                                              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                                  image: DecorationImage(
                                                      image: NetworkImage(
                                                          productList[index]
                                                              .getImage()))),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Padding(
                                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                                                right: 8, left: 8, top: 8),
                                            child: Center(
                                              child: Text(productList[index]
                                                  .getTitle()),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          Center(
                                            child: Text(
                                              productList[index].getPrice(),
                                              style: TextStyle(
                                                  color: Colors.green),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ],
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  );
                          }),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )),
        ));
  }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should cover your second ListView.builder SizedBox with height:190 instead of Expanded like first ListView.builder because ListView.builder widget have infinite height so you should cover it specific height.

Sample:

```
 SizedBox(
  height: 190,
  child: ListView.builder(....
```

Comment: I test it your code before you can check it link http://prntscr.com/pxkrkf it is going to infinity, after http://prntscr.com/pxksdk it will be OK maybe you should re-debug app sometimes hotloading not work well

Comment: I put the column widget in SingleChildScrollView and it solved,thank you

Comment: Yes it can be solution I am glad to solve problem. You are welcome